# Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at cursor.pl line 5

Tags: oracle, perl

Tengo esta secuencia de comandos Perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while () {
    if (/^PARSING IN CURSOR/../END OF STMT/) {
        if (/^PARSING IN CURSOR/) {
            s/^PARSING IN CURSOR \#//;
            s/ [a-z]+=/!/g;
            s/\n$/!/;
            $_="$.!$_";
        }
        unless (/^END OF STMT/) {
            print;
        }
    }
}
```

y me muestra el mensaje:

> Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at cursor.pl line 5

Comment: Hola, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general). Deberías editar la pregunta para añadir algo más de información: ¿qué es lo que hace el script? ¿cuál es el resultado esperado? ¿cómo lo llamas? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está dentro de la condición del `while()`.

Lo más probable es que falte `<>`, que es el operador de lectura de archivos pasados como argumentos o la entrada estándar.

El mensaje de error se refiere a que la variable por defecto `$_` no tiene ningún valor, no se ha inicializado.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta en efecto faltaba <> para que pueda leer el archivo.